# Estimating Product Rate Sensitivity to Market Rate Changes: First Difference With Interactive Variable

Tags: interest-rates, replication

I am currently trying to understand and estimate the sensitivity of deposit rate sensitivity to market rate changes. My current model:

$\Delta$$R_t$ $=$ $\alpha$ $+$ $\beta_1$$*$$\Delta$$FFR_{t-1}$$+$$\beta_2$($\Delta$$FFR_{t-1}$$*$$I^+$)

Where

- $\Delta$$R_t$ is the first difference deposit rate
- $\Delta$$FFR_{t-1}$ is the lagged first difference of the Fed Funds Rate
- $I^+$ is the censor variable where if $\Delta$$FFR$$<$ $0$ then $I^+$$=$$0$ otherwise $I^+$$=$$1$

I originally wanted to include 3 lags of FFR, but I run into collinearity problems. Additional, my hypothesis was that in increasing rate environments ( $\Delta$$FFR$ is positive), deposit sensitivity would be less than that in down rate environments ($\Delta$$FFR$ is negative). My results from the model estimate that in an increasing environments my deposit rate sensitivity is much larger than that in down rate environments, results below:

- $\beta_1$ $=$ $.35$
- $\beta_2$ $=$ $.40$

So in downrate environment the deposit rate sensitivity is equal to .35 while in an uprate environment the deposit rate sensitivity is equal to .75. The results are statistically significant, but I'm not convinced by the results. I am wondering if an error correction model is more appropriate in these circumstances? Further, since there is an interactive variable, $\beta_2$($\Delta$$FFR_{t-1}$$*$$I^+$), what is the best way that I fit the regression to my data?